# var_dump() returning zero arry. unable to upload file PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, var-dump, language-construct

upload.php

The var_dump() function is returning zero array. What am i doing wrong here ?

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php">

    <input type="file" name ="file" id="file"><input type="submit" value="upload">

</form>
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['file']))
{   


   var_dump($_FILES);


}   
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the **`form`** enctype

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form to upload files

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) for more